# Amazon DyanamoDB health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, connectivity, health-monitoring, availability, amazon-dynamodb

I tried to find that "How to check Amazon DynamoDB's availability and connectivity"

And I found some ways :

1. Availability Check

   (1) Using CURL command

   - When I using CURL command, that only return HTTP 200 status code.
   - Command Example:  curl -X GET -w "{"status": "%{http_code}", "response_time":"%{time_total}"}" https://dynamodb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
   - Result Example :
     healthy: dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com {status: 200, response_time:0.688000}

   (2) Using AWS health API
2. Connectivity Check AWS health

   (1) Ping Test

   (2) Using JDBC, ODBC driver to connection Test

   (3) Using ddbcli package

   (4) Using AWS SDK

I can't using sdk and other ways.

Is there any way to check AWS DynamoDB's Health check like availability and connectivity?

Comment: what is the meaning of heath check? working connection with the given dynamo DB endpoint?

Comment: https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: health check means, check availability and connectivity in my local machine like this : 

1) DynamoDB instance is working
   - instance is running, and who can access instance
   - or dynamodb is enabled.

2) user can connect dynamodb
  - connection test is successful
  - when user connecting, what is response time

and I want get check result in java application using accesskey and secretkey, region.